# Upload image without resizing but insert in post with resizing

Tags: customization, post-thumbnails, images

OK so I tried to find this problem in whole web but didn't got any solution.
.
basically.
I have set in my **Options** > **Media Settings** :

```
Medium size :   Max Width : 500px| Max height : 500px
```

When I upload images of different size to my media library it upload and creates **3** versions.
like if I upload :
**roses.png** of size 700px X 800 px
it creates
**roses500x500.png** 
**roses200x200.png** 
and the original : **roses.png**

---

I want to insert original image **roses.png** with size 500x500 px.
.
means `<img class="aligncenter" src="http://somesite/wp-content/uploads/roses.png" width="500px" height="500px" />`
but when I am inserting it in post with selection *500x 500 px*
It is adding this :
 `<img class="aligncenter" src="http://somesite/wp-content/uploads/roses-500x500.png" width="500px" height="500px" />`
Which is not the original image, but modified by wordpress image.
Any solutions??
I want that, when i insert image in wordpress post with size 500x500px. by clicking [Add Media]
It should give me output 
 `<img class="aligncenter" src="http://somesite/wp-content/uploads/roses.png" width="500px" height="500px" />`
.
If there is any plugin or anything just let me know..

Comment: If your image is 700x800 and you force it to be 500x500 wont it be distorted?

Answer (score 0):

You should choose "full" under size on attachment display settings (right bottom) when inserting an image to get the full version.

or you could always just remove the "-500x500" from the href